How to protect /swagger/v1/swagger.json route when using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore?
I need to document a web api. For this, I am using Swagger. To protect the doc, I am using RoutePrefix, only authorized persons can access, only who knows the correct RoutePrefix (it is a guid). But anyone who knows the basepath of my application, when access for example myapp.com/swagger/v1/swagger.json can view the content. How can I protect this endpoint?
I have tried to use a middleware, I think this is a little bit complex for my problem.

Usually swagger is not used in production environments, it is generally used in development environments.
That we can find IsDevelopment condition in default template.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

As we know middleware can capture all http request, so we can limit it by identifying the URL (/swagger/v1/swagger.json), which is the simplest method， not complex.
Here is the sample for you.
public class SwaggerAuthMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private const string SwaggerEndpoint = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
    private const string AuthHeaderName = "X-Swagger-Auth-Key";
    private const string AuthKey = "YourSecretKey"; // authkey in header

    public SwaggerAuthMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(SwaggerEndpoint))
        {
            if (!context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(AuthHeaderName, out var extractedAuthKey))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized access to Swagger documentation.");
                return;
            }

            if (!AuthKey.Equals(extractedAuthKey))
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden access to Swagger documentation.");
                return;
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

